# c# How do I open the combobox when the button is clicked

Tags: c#, combobox, buttonclick

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) { 
cb_brand_Click(cb_brand, new EventArgs());
}
```

detected as clicked, but not detected as a directory after adding and refreshing the data I typed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) { 
    comboBox1.DroppedDown = true;
}
```

Comment: it worked yeah but i can see it pops up can there be another solution

Comment: No I do not think unless you want to customize the control and make custom settings there which is a bit complicated

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can try this,

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        comboBox1.Focus();
        comboBox1.DroppedDown = true;
    }
```

Comment: it worked yeah but i can see it pops up can there be another solution

Comment: I pull the data from the database, if not, I load the data in the text of the data combox to the database, and then I need to renew it because I add data according to the index of the combobox, but when I renew, the index shows as -1 unless I open the combobox.

Comment: As i have understand you are trying to load a list of data from database to your combobox. Are you disposing the data you have loaded initially before you refresh?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what you are wanting to do but this should open ComboBox1 so you could put it in your on click event of the button. obviously change the name of ComboBox1 to whatever your combo box is called.

```
ComboBox1.DroppedDown = !ComboBox1.DroppedDown;
```